# How to make the global \lineskiplimit still valid in list?

Tags: lists, line-spacing

I have set that

```
    \lineskiplimit = 6pt
    \lineskip=6pt
```

in the very begin of my **Chinese** document to prevent the space between above-and-below inline math from being too narrow. But the content in the `list` environment are not affected by them. So how can I make the global  `\lineskiplimit` and `\lineskip` settings still work in the sub environment, such as `list`? Is something like below an ideal way?

```
\begin{list}{(\roman{iItemcounter})}
{\usecounter{iItemcounter}
\itemsep =0pt\parsep=0pt\parskip=0pt\topsep=0pt\leftmargin = 5em\rightmargin = 1em\lineskiplimit = 6pt\lineskip=6pt}{
\item ...
\item ...
}
\end{list}
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm sorry that I just found that the problem does not belong to the list environment, but the `minipage`. I surrounded the `list` by the `minipage`.

Comment: are you really sure you want to set lineskiplimit to 6pt???????????

Comment: if `\lineskip` ends up being used at all it is usually a sign of a failure of the text to fit the constraints of the document layout, increasing the value just magnifies the unpleasant effects of the discontinuity in the baseline spacing. It is hard to say without any example but there must be a better way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm typesetting a Chinese document for senior high and I have a lot of special design for it (to suit the custom for Chinese readers), so....

Comment: ah it may make sense with Chinese:-) (perhaps)  Although increasing \baselineskip would give more consistent spacing even then. I'll post an answer:-)

Comment: actually \lineskip` is set in parboxes but I don't see why it should be reset in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general `\lineskip` is to be avoided, at least when typesetting with latin based scripts, but in comments you indicated this is Chinese about which I know nothing so...

latex has

```
\def\normalbaselines{\lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit}
```

so you should set `\normallineskip` and `\normallineskiplimit` to your 6pt values.

You provided no example  but in parbox and minipage `\lineskip` is reset to `\normallineskip` so you would lose a setting if you only set `\lineskip` at the start of the document, but I don't see why the default list setting should rest that, but perhaps your class redefines things. Hopefully though it resets to the
`\normallineskiplimit` value.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry that I just found that the problem does not belong to the list environment, but the minipage. I surrounded the list by the minipage. You are so bright and detective. Even I has made a mistake, I also learn the usage of `\normallineskip` from your answer. Thanks!